# Why is paragraph object access so slow?

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word, vsto

I'm building my own VSTO to replace the standard cross reference function in Word. It's working pretty good but I hit a performance drain accessing the outlineLevel property of paragraph objects. I use the outlineLevel to format the referenceable items in a data grid view that is part of a custom task pane. Word does not properly outline numbered items in their own cross reference panel and I'm beginning to suspect why ... each call to the paragraph.outlineLevel property takes approx. 0.05seconds but the CPU load on Winword.exe is only 5-10%.

Why is it taking so long and how can I improve the code to retrieve the outline level?

My code builds a list of headers and numbered items (a merged list in contrast to Word's own separated lists) by scanning all paragraphs in a document, checking against GetCrossReferenceItems to build a list of insertable references.

Except for the call to .Paragraphs.OutlineLevel this code is quick, scanning a 40 page contract document to build a list (400 referenceable items) and displaying it in a custom taks pane takes 2-3 seconds, until I add the call to .Paragraphs.OutlineLevel, then it spikes up to 10-20 seconds depending on document content.

The weird thing is I have a larger document (2x size) with 10% more calls to .Parapgraphs.OutlineLevel but does so 4x faster! (2s vs 8s). The difference is that the large document has 95% numbered items and 5% headings while the smaller document that ratio is about 60/40.

Extract of the code:

```
For each para in In Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    with para.Range

        ' This part is quick -> it does 400 paragraphs in under 0.5s
        ' Collect .text, .ListFormat.ListString, ListNumber, listLevel etc 
        ' Store in own array, array of type, redimmed based on paragraphs.count before I enter the for loop
        ....
        my_paras(paras_found).number = .ListFormat.ListString
        my_paras(paras_found).listLevel = .ListFormat.ListLevelNumber
        my_paras(paras_found).referenceText = aReferences(refCount).number + " " + Trim(Left(.Text, Len(.Text) - 1))
        ....

       ' The listlevel is a pretty accurate reflection of the outline level, 
       ' except for numbered lists of level 1 
       ' get the outline level for the paragraphs of list level 1

       ' This line is a performance killer, for 150 items in my_paras 
       ' it takes 8 seconds
       if my_paras(paras_found).listLevel = 1 then my_paras(paras_found).outlinelevel = .Paragraphs.OutlineLevel

        paras_found = paras_found + 1

    end with
next
```

Comment: I'm not extremely knowledgeable on the Word object model, but I do not see the `listlevel` property listed for the the [Word.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range_members.aspx) object.  Have you by chance used `On Error Resume Next` in this code combined with `Option Strict Off`?  If so, you may be _eating_ a late-bound error exception in that statement.  Exceptions are extremely time consuming.

Comment: you are correct, it is part of the .ListFormat property and my actual code is correct. I'll update my code example above from If .listLevel to if my_paras(paras_found).listLevel.

Comment: You could try moving the `End With` up two lines. This would enable you to simplify your current `para.Range.Paragraphs.OutlineLevel` to `para.OutlineLevel`.

Comment: @m4o_tim, good one! It has knocked of quite a bit of time I'm now getting 5-8 seconds where it used to be about double that. Thanks!

Comment: and was able to knock of another second and fix a bug by skipping any table of contents, by adding this after the `With paras` 
`For Each TOC In `
`Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents`
 
`If .InRange(TOC.Range) Then GoTo nextLoop `

`Next`

Comment: In the same category as the suggestion from @m4o_tim, you should create a local reference to interop objects used multiple times.  i.e. `.ListFormat.ListString` and `.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber` require pulling the same`ListFormat` object twice.